# php sending mail doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

I have some problem here, I don't see the mistake, it was sending mail before I started using the POST var, but after I set them, mail is not sending, but I still see the screenOK.

```
$full_name=$_POST["full_name"];                 
$to      = 'admin@mail.com';
$subject = 'Call me';
$message = "call $full_name";
$headers = 'From: admin@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: '. "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo '<script>
$("submit").click(screenOk);
</script>';
}
else echo 'STH got wrong';
?>
```

the form is here:

```
<form action=notify.php method=POST>
                <div class=field>
                    <label for=full_name class=full-name>
                        <svg ...>...</svg>
                    </label>
                    <input name=subscriber[full_name] id=full_name placeholder="Your name" class="js-page text-field" data-page=/NameField></div>
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: If i were you i use phpmailer or swiftmailer to send emails with php

Answer (score 0):

Your form input is named subscriber[full_name] but you're trying to access it using

```
$_POST['full_name']
```

Try changing these to match;

for instance;

```
<input name="full_name" >
```

Some reading material: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: please throw in a lecture about reading the manual. i'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try it 
you POST variable not matching

```
<input name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Your name" class="js-page text-field" data-page=/NameField>
```